# Web API Identity User with JWT on two API's sharing the same Auth params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am really struggling to find the answer to this question. I have created a registration WebApi that is working. I can register a user, again roles, login and receive back a JWT. This api will be hosted online to allow users to access my page.

The frontend is a Blazor Web Assembly Application. This also communicates to another API, this API is installed locally on a clients machine, that allows communication to another application.

A lot of these calls to the local api need to be authorized.

This is the part I am really struggling to find an answer for.

How do I get this API to authorize against the JWT that is being given out by the other API. All documentation I have found bundles these features together.

What have I tried?
I have tried added the same auth properties to this local api, but it appears I will also need to provide it access to the database for it to build, which of course isn't ideal and doesn't seem correct.

If someone could give me some pointers, that would be fantastic!

Comment: I have been able to get this to work by coping over the Authentication settings from the auth api start up to the local api start up. This appears to be working. But is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To authenticate the requests with the other API, that API must validate the token with the same secret it was signed with.

So, if you're issuing the token with:

```cs
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var accessToken = jwtHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: _environment.ApplicationName,
    audience: _environment.ApplicationName,
    subject: principal.Identities.First(),
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_options.ExpirationMinutes),
    signingCredentials: _options.SigningCredentials // <-- key used to sign the token
);
```

The other service must validate it with the same key:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(/*...*/).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // ValidateIssuer = false,
        // ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, // <--
        IssuerSigningKey = jwtOptions.SigningCredentials.Key, // <-- same key
    };
});
```

The only thing you really need to share between the apps is the signing key.

But this isn't ideal if you're dealing with more apps. Would you share the key with all of them? You might, but what happens if you need to reset the key? You'd have to reset it in all apps.

For those cases, a better solution would be to delegate the token signing to a separate service, like Identity Server (or any other OIDC provider), then use & validate the tokens issued by that service in all apps.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I was half way there! You raise some valid points.